# how to send keys to elmint hide item with calss unfiled

Tags: python

```
<input aria-label="Create a username" type="text" class="ScInputBase-sc-1wz0osy-0 ScInput-sc-m6vr9t-0 fQdJFL jjBhRF InjectLayout-sc-588ddc-0 bnQUex tw-input" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" data-a-target="tw-input" id="signup-username" value="">
```

how to send_keys in this elamint

```
my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@class="ScInputBase-sc-1wz0osy-0 ScInput-sc-m6vr9t-0 fQdJFL jjBhRF InjectLayout-sc-588ddc-0 bnQUex tw-input" and @id="signup-username"]')))
my_element.click()
my_element.clear()
my_element.send_keys("vzcxvzcx")
```

Comment: <input aria-label="Create a username" type="text" class="ScInputBase-sc-1wz0osy-0 ScInput-sc-m6vr9t-0 fQdJFL jjBhRF InjectLayout-sc-588ddc-0 bnQUex tw-input" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" data-a-target="tw-input" id="signup-username" value="">

Comment: do you get error or what? Show it in question (not in comments) But without real URL we can't see what can makes problem.